# Ce stage amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, circuit-design, gain, common-emitter

[image]I wanna design a ce stage amplifier with this specification :
Gain 20
Rc=10k
Max swing
The simiulation of the circuit is not the same with may calculations,
How can i solve this? [image]

what i get from calculation are:
IcQ=0.4775mA
vceQ=5V
RE=0.47k
vc=5.225V
vb=0.925v
R1=4.7k
R2=46.24k
Max swing =4.775v
But when i replace these in the circuit the result is not what i wanted.

Comment: *The simiulation of the circuit is not the same with may calculations* What did you expect, did you expect to have **EXACTLY** 5.000 V swing at the output? With a 10 V supply, that's **never** going to happen. Your hand calculations are **always** a simplification and so is the simulation. If my sim. and hand results match within 10% I'm usually happy with that, it is **close enough**. Stop focusing on getting **exact numbers** because you will not get them (not with this circuit).

Comment: So the output makes sense? But the swing is too diffrent with hand max swing that i get.

Comment: You're just inputting something (2 mV) and expecting that the output will be what you calculated. 1) your calculation might be wrong 2) your calculation might disregard some effects that the simulator does take into account. Start by **fully understanding everything that happens** by determining the amplitude at every relevant point in the circuit. Start at the voltage source V3, is the amplitude correct? Then at the base of the transistor, is it correct? If not: determine **why?** that is so.

Comment: Look at the datasheet for your transistor. Note the minimum , maximum and typical gain (hfe) for that transistor in the datasheet, at the closest conditions to yours (probably Ic= 1mA or 10mA). Re-run the simulation with hfe set to all those figures. That's the spread of results you can expect with real transistors.